# How to create a due date based off a weekly offset in TFS custom work item

Tags: tfs, workitem

How can I create a default date based off a time offset for a work item in TFS WIT definition?

In  section of the WIT, you can define FIELD values. Is it possible to have, say a "NumberOfWeeks" FIELD and then generate a DueDate when the work item is first created? (Transitions from "" to "Open" states). I know you can default to the system clock, but can you add an offset to that?

The idea is, when creating a custom Task, the user will put a number in "NumberOfWeeks" and when that work item is created, it will take the current date plus the number of weeks and populate a due date with that date.

Currently using TFS2015.

Comment: Sorry, not totally got your point, for example, did you mean you want to create a task at 2018/02/08 and actually the task is at 2018/05/08 (multiple weeks later)  Why you need this feature, for time tracking?

Comment: Yeah, basically I want to set a due date based off the time of creation. So like, you would create a task at 2018/05/08 and give it a 1 week time. Then, due date would automatically be set to 1 week in the future. That way, I could write a query that will pull all tasks that are past due. I could potentially just have them write out a due date, but it would be easier if they could just give a number of weeks and have the due date generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to create a filed similar to [Original Estimate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/office/rollup-estimated-and-actual-work-using-project) . TFS will auto generated the due date based on the values creator specify and it will follow the rule as `due date= work item creator time+ NumberOfWeeks`

It also have similar functions like a calculated "Days in State" field, and "Days since created" for tracking workitems.

What you are looking for is a kind of **calculated fields** in TFS.

Unfortunately,this is not support for now, there had been a related uservoice, you could take a look at below links:

> **Support calculated fields in TFS**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/3595615-support-calculated-fields-in-tfs?page=1&per_page=20

Comment: I'm not trying to modify the Created Date, I want to automatically generated a date in a custom field with a date offset from the Created Date. For example, if the Created Date is 2/8/2018 and the user enters 2 weeks, I want a due date automatically created with a date of 2/22/2018. End result, I want to have a due date I can query to get all tasks past due, but I don't want the users to have to manually calculate future dates, but instead just enter the number of weeks until the item is due.

Comment: @whoknows  Thank you for your feedback!  Sorry for the misunderstanding,What you are looking for, it's unsupport for now. You may  just have them write out a due date as a workaround for now. Details please see my update reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [TFSAggregator](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator). This plugin will allow you to calculate the fields.

Example:
[Calculate Fields](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/wiki/Policy-Examples#calculated-field)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, they're pretty strict about plugins and was hoping for a native solution. If they decide to open up a little, I'll check this out.